# Assuring unique values in set of #define statements

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, unique, preprocessor

I have a set of tasks with different priorities. I manage the priorities as `#define` statements in a `.h` file:

```
#define PRIO_TASK_A 1
#define PRIO_TASK_B 2
#define PRIO_TASK_C 3
// ...
```

As the list of tasks is rather long, making sure that no two tasks have the same priority is prone to error. What is the best way to check for uniqueness? E.g. that the following does not happen: `PRIO_TASK_A` = 4 and `PRIO_TASK_B` = 4.

Comment: On which platform are you ?

Comment: Is using `#define` required? Isn't using `enum` acceptable?

Comment: You have not specified the problem fully, or at least not clearly. For example, do you want to **generate** unique values for each macro, by having the compiler provide them, say with a counter, or do you want to **check** that values typed by humans for the macros are unique?

Comment: If you just want the macro values to be unique, then numbering them with consecutive integers is obviously sufficient. If you want the compiler to generate values, you can define each macro after the first in the pattern `#define PRIO_TASK_B (PRIO_TASK_A+1)`. Or you can write code to generate the macro definitions and write them to a file that is included in your compilation.

Comment: If you want to check for uniqueness, you will have to write code for that. It might be best to write a program that inspects the macro definitions in their source/header file and checks them.

Comment: One way to check for uniqueness is to write a `switch` statement and use each macro as a case label.  The compiler will complain if there's a repeated value.  Normally though, that's not necessary.  People can spot repeats.  You'd probably not include the switch in code that's compiled every day.  If you did, you'd probably make it into a `static inline` function that is never called.  The biggest risk is forgetting to add new names to the body of the switch.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
@MikeCAT `enum` would be acceptable. However, I would like to be able to use non-consecutive numbers for the task priorities. E.g. ```PRIO_TASK_A = 10; PRIO_TASK_B = 5, PRIO_TASK_C = 1;``` So I would have to use the "manual assignment of values" in the `enum.` That way, uniqueness is not granted any more. The same applies for suggested solutions with `+1` patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro solution! Disclaimer, I don't think its clean, it relies on the `__COUNTER__` macro (which is gcc specific), the problem sounds like its better handled by an enum, and it would likely mess up any other area of your program that uses the `__COUNTER__` macro.

Here is a sample program with some explanation.

```
//  macro for using compile time checks

//// The "_H" Helper macro defines a unique type with the priority of the task baked into the typename
//// The __COUNTER__ macro makes this typedef name a different type from all other SA_UNIQUE_PRIO_CALLS
//// We need a helper macro so that the VAL argument can be expanded to its int literal value
#define SA_UNIQUE_PRIO_H(VAL) typedef char static_assertion_uniq_prio_##VAL[__COUNTER__]

//// This macro is what should be called - guarantees that all asserts to it at compile time take a different value
#define STATIC_ASSERT_UNIQUE_PRIO(VAL) SA_UNIQUE_PRIO_H(VAL)

// \ end macro


// Define your priorities here
#define PRIO_TASK_A 1
#define PRIO_TASK_B 2
#define PRIO_TASK_C 3
#define PRIO_TASK_D 1


// check for uniqueness here.
STATIC_ASSERT_UNIQUE_PRIO(PRIO_TASK_A);
STATIC_ASSERT_UNIQUE_PRIO(PRIO_TASK_B);
STATIC_ASSERT_UNIQUE_PRIO(PRIO_TASK_C);
STATIC_ASSERT_UNIQUE_PRIO(PRIO_TASK_D);

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Note-  I think you would have to put the `STATIC_ASSERT_UNIQUE_PRIO` calls in a c file, since if it is included in multiple files, then there will be conflicting typedefs.

Comment: Solution is not resistant to `#define A 16`, `#define B 0x10`. Moreover, defines could not be constant expressions like `#define C (1+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XMacro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to manage constants. This approach lets defining all constants in one place. Moreover arbitrary constant expression can be used. The solution works in C99 and above without any compiler specific extensions.
The main disadvantage is that a value of all constants must fit to `int`.

```
#define PRIO_TASK__XMACRO(X) \
  X(PRIO_TASK_A, 1) \
  X(PRIO_TASK_B, 2) \
  X(PRIO_TASK_C, 3) \
  X(PRIO_TASK_D, 1+1)
```

Instantiate the constant as a anonymous enum:

```
#define DECLARE_ENUM(NAME,VALUE) NAME = VALUE,

enum {
PRIO_TASK__XMACRO(DECLARE_ENUM)
};
```

As suggested in the comment by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), use `switch` to detect if a value was ever repeated.

```
static inline void check_unique_enums(int c) {
  switch (c) {
#define CASE_ENUM(NAME, VALUE) case NAME: break;
PRIO_TASK__XMACRO(CASE_ENUM)
  }
}
```

Compiling with gcc produced errors:

```
so.c: In function ‘check_unique_enums’:
so.c:15:32: error: duplicate case value
   15 | #define CASE_ENUM(NAME, VALUE) case NAME: break;
      |                                ^~~~
so.c:5:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘CASE_ENUM’
    5 |   X(PRIO_TASK_D, 1+1)
      |   ^
so.c:16:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRIO_TASK__XMACRO’
   16 | PRIO_TASK__XMACRO(CASE_ENUM)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
so.c:15:32: note: previously used here
   15 | #define CASE_ENUM(NAME, VALUE) case NAME: break;
      |                                ^~~~
so.c:3:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘CASE_ENUM’
    3 |   X(PRIO_TASK_B, 2) \
      |   ^
so.c:16:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRIO_TASK__XMACRO’
   16 | PRIO_TASK__XMACRO(CASE_ENUM)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```